# JS return only 1st id's value from array after hide undefined value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am sent many dynamic post ids from a page and a php server side page(server.php) make a query with those id to find out **newly added data** in mysql.

If it *not found* any **newly added data** in mysql, it's return a `undefined` value. So I added this `if (msg.id !== undefined && msg.detail !== undefined && msg.name !== undefined) { //do here }` to hide undefined.

But after added the above line, my script hide `undefined` value well but return only for 1st CID's newly added value.

That means If CID sent ids(100, 101, 102, 103 ect.) to php, It's return only 100 id's newly added value and append it.

Where is problem here please?

**N.B.** Without above line its returned all CID's value well but return also `undefined` value if no new data found.

my javascript:

```
var CID = []; // Get all dynamic ids of posts (works well)
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

function addrep(type, msg){
CID.forEach(function(id){
if (msg.id !== undefined && msg.detail !== undefined && msg.name !== undefined) {
    $("#newreply"+id).append("<div class='"+ type +""+ msg.id +"'><ul><div class='newkochi'>"+ msg.name +"</div><div class='cdomment_text'>"+ msg.detail +"</ul></div>");
}
});
}

function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {CID : CID},
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
            setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000 );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000); }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
```

server.php

```
while (true) {
    if($_GET['CID']){  //cid got all dynamic post id as: 1,2,3,4 etc.
      foreach($_GET['CID'] as $key => $value){

        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 second'));
        $res = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM reply WHERE qazi_id=".$_GET['tutid']."  AND date >= '$datetime' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $data = array();
        while($rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

          $data[]=$rows;

          $data['id'] = $rows['id']; 
          $data['qazi_id'] = $rows['qazi_id'];
          $data['username'] = $rows['username'];
          $data['description'] = $rows['description'];
          $data['date'] = $rows['date'];
          //etc. all
             $id = $rows['id'];
             $qazi_id = $rows['qazi_id'];
             $username = $rows['username'];
             $description = $rows['description'];
             //etc. all
          } //while close
      } //foreach close

          $name .='<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>';
          $detail .=''.$description.'';

          $data['name'] = $name;
          $data['detail'] = $detail;
          // do others something more like as above

           if (!empty($data)) {
              echo json_encode($data);
              flush();
              exit(0);
           }

    } //request close
    sleep(5);
} //while close
```

Comment: You have LIMIT 1 in your SQL string, so the query fetches just one row. And you should escape REQUEST parameters in the query string to avoid SQL-injections

Comment: Ok remove REQUEST, But LIMIT 1 is not any factor for this But also remove it and not work.

Answer (score 0):

Spotted Issues in javascript:

Fix 1:

```
var CID = [$('div[data-post-id]').length]; 

$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});
```

Fix 2:

```
var CID = []; 
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
CID.push($(this).data('post-id'));
});
```

Insert issue:

```
function addrep(type, msg){
CID.forEach(function(id){
//You are inserting the comment in all html tags havin id ='newreplay' + id
//Here you need to correct you logic like: if (msg.id == id) //do something

if (msg.id !== undefined && msg.detail !== undefined && msg.name !== undefined) {
    $("#newreply"+id).append("<div class='"+ type +""+ msg.id +"'><ul><div class='newkochi'>"+ msg.name +"</div><div class='cdomment_text'>"+ msg.detail +"</ul></div>");
}
});
}
```

Comment: My php file got all ids well which I already mention above, And I am not think about where the comment display. It's will be my next Question. My current script get and returned all except I add the above JS line. But the JS line added for `undefined' value. Thank u.